# How can we make existing text selectable in a textview ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, uitextview

I want to get all text selectable whenever user clicks on textview (objective c), I have tried the following code in textViewDidBeginEditing method but it is not working for me.

```
[textView selectAll:nil];
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689911/programmatically-select-all-text-in-uitextfield and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307436/uitextview-selectall-method-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView selectAll method not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307436/uitextview-selectall-method-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: @arpita yes, I had gone through those links too, but they didn't work for me. :(

Comment: @AntonyRaphel actually I am using custom classes for text view, but I checked those classes, didn't get any code for selection of text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403538/how-to-make-uitextview-text-all-selectable-and-show-copy-option-to-the-user-ipho. try this